# Exception handling in this scenario

Tags: java, spring, jsp, exception, servlets

Trying my hands on Java for the first time, please be kind. I have following code in a Web Controller where a service is called based on enclosed Switch-Case statement. 
 
Issue I am facing is, if the service call throws an Exception, this exception gets shown on the JSP page. Basically the code never reaches the lines:

```
if(!statusFlag)
{
      model.addAttribute("statusFlag", statusFlag);
      return "myJspPage"
}
```

How do I make sure the executing goes to above lines, even though an exception is thrown in the WebService call at:

```
statusFlag = myWebService.getMeStatus();
```

Should I enclose the whole Switch Statement inside try-catch block?

Snippet:

```
@Controller
public String mySpringController() throws Exception
{
   //rest of the controller code
        switch ( condition )
        {
        case MAY :
                   statusFlag = myWebService.getMeStatus();

                   if(!statusFlag)
                   {
                      model.addAttribute("statusFlag", statusFlag);

                      return "myJspPage"
                   }
                   break;

        case JUNE :
                   statusFlag = myWebService.getMeStatus();

                   if(!statusFlag)
                   {
                      model.addAttribute("statusFlag", statusFlag);

                      return "myJspPage"
                   }
                   break;

        case JULY :
                   statusFlag = myWebService.getMeStatus();

                   if(!statusFlag)
                   {
                      model.addAttribute("statusFlag", statusFlag);

                      return "myJspPage"
                   }
                   break;
        default:

                  //Do something by default.

        }

return "myJspPage";

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that line is throwing an Exception it means that it is never returning, so `statusFlag` is still with its original value and the execution of that method has stopped. You need to surround it in a `try - catch` if you want to catch the Exception and do something about it.

I see you are using Spring. In Spring Controllers you can also have your own special methods which get invoked when an Exception occurs. Using the `@ExceptionHandler` annotation.

Comment: Hi jbx, @ExceptionHandler sounds good. So just declare a common method in the controller with this annotation and it's going to be invoked anytime exception is thrown?

Comment: Yes, you can even have multiple ones if you want different behaviours depending on which Exception is thrown. However, this is Spring-specific. If you are rusty in Java you need to understand a bit more how error handling works. In Java it is discouraged to have error detection by checking error codes (like old C-style code) because it has various disadvantages (error handling becomes optional, error handling is mixed with normal 'positive' code, you have to dig in to find further info while an Exception carries all the information with it which can be different for each error, etc.)

Comment: appreciate your response. You guys must have figured out by now I am coming from C background lol.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the purpose of your switch statement since each case does the same thing.

But basically you can put your webservice call in a try-catch block

```
try{
    webservice.call();
}
catch (Exception e){
   // handle the exception
}
finally{
  //anything in here will be executed regardless if an exception is caught or not
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're writing Java in the style of C++, where you're returning error codes and then checking them to determine whether anything went wrong.  There are a number of issues with this snippet, but the reason for the exception display is that you never `catch` the exception that's being thrown.  Where you should put your `try-catch` block depends on what the exception means; if it's something that isn't specific to a particular month, then yes, enclose the entire `switch` statement to share the error handling.

As an aside, did you copy and paste your actual code, or did you try to retype an example?  Those `case` blocks all look identical.

Comment: Hello Chrylis, Thanks for the help. I just typed some skeleton code.